# Itext create XMP in pdf with Java

Tags: java, itext, metadata, xmp

I need to create in java (using itext) the following xmp metadata and to put it in one of my pdf.

```
<rdf:Description rdf:about="" xmlns:pdfaExtension="http://www.aiim.org/pdfa/ns/extension/" xmlns:pdfaSchema="http://www.aiim.org/pdfa/ns/schema#" xmlns:pdfaProperty="http://www.aiim.org/pdfa/ns/property#" xmlns:pdfaType="http://www.aiim.org/pdfa/ns/type#" xmlns:pdfaField="http://www.aiim.org/pdfa/ns/field#"> <pdfaExtension:schemas>
<rdf:Bag>
<rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
<pdfaSchema:schema>ABI Assegni Schema</pdfaSchema:schema> <pdfaSchema:namespaceURI>http://abi.it/std/cheque/xmlns</pdfaSchema:namespaceURI> <pdfaSchema:prefix>assegni</pdfaSchema:prefix>
<pdfaSchema:property>
    <rdf:Seq>
<rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
<pdfaProperty:name>IDDocumento</pdfaProperty:name> <pdfaProperty:valueType>Text</pdfaProperty:valueType> <pdfaProperty:category>external</pdfaProperty:category> <pdfaProperty:description>Identificativo univoco del documento</pdfaProperty:description>
</rdf:li>
<rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
<pdfaProperty:name>datachiusura</pdfaProperty:name> <pdfaProperty:valueType>Date</pdfaProperty:valueType> <pdfaProperty:category>external</pdfaProperty:category> <pdfaProperty:description>Data e ora della produzione del file</pdfaProperty:description>
</rdf:li>
<rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
<pdfaProperty:name>oggettodocumento</pdfaProperty:name> <pdfaProperty:valueType>Text</pdfaProperty:valueType> <pdfaProperty:category>external</pdfaProperty:category> <pdfaProperty:description>Oggetto del documento</pdfaProperty:description>
</rdf:li>
<rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
<pdfaProperty:name>soggettoproduttore</pdfaProperty:name> <pdfaProperty:valueType>soggetto</pdfaProperty:valueType> <pdfaProperty:category>external</pdfaProperty:category> <pdfaProperty:description>Soggetto produttore</pdfaProperty:description>
</rdf:li>
<rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
<pdfaProperty:name>destinatario</pdfaProperty:name> <pdfaProperty:valueType>soggetto</pdfaProperty:valueType> <pdfaProperty:category>external</pdfaProperty:category> <pdfaProperty:description>Destinatario</pdfaProperty:description>
</rdf:li> </rdf:Seq>

</pdfaSchema:property>
</rdf:li>
</rdf:Bag>
</pdfaExtension:schemas>
</rdf:Description>
```

Until now I tried this portion of code:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(baos.toByteArray());
        PdfAStamper stamper = new PdfAStamper(reader, baos,     PdfAConformanceLevel.PDF_A_1B);

        String namespaceExtension = new    String("http://www.aiim.org/pdfa/ns/extension/");
        String namespaceSchema = new String("http://www.aiim.org/pdfa/ns/schema#");
        String namespaceProperty = new String("http://www.aiim.org/pdfa/ns/property#");
        String namespaceType = new String("http://www.aiim.org/pdfa/ns/type#");
        String namespaceField = new String("http://www.aiim.org/pdfa/ns/field#");
        XMPSchemaRegistry registry = XMPMetaFactory.getSchemaRegistry();
        registry.registerNamespace(namespaceExtension, "pdfaExtension");
        registry.registerNamespace(namespaceSchema, "pdfaSchema");
        registry.registerNamespace(namespaceProperty, "pdfaProperty");
        registry.registerNamespace(namespaceType, "pdfaType");
        registry.registerNamespace(namespaceField, "pdfaField");

        XmpWriter w = new XmpWriter(baos);
        w.appendArrayItem(namespaceExtension, "schemas", "a");

        w.close();

        writer.setXmpMetadata(baos.toByteArray());
```

And the created xmp is the following:

```
<pdfaExtension:schemas>
    <rdf:Bag>
      <rdf:li>a</rdf:li>
    </rdf:Bag>
```

Now I can't understand on how to go on. Any idea on how to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried? Which version of iText are you using? Starting from a certain 5.x.y version (I didn't check which one), iText uses a library provided by Adobe to create XMP. With iText 7, the API changed completely, so please don't expect an answer without sharing the iText version you are using.

Comment: I've tried this:
XmpWriter w = new XmpWriter(baos);
   w.appendArrayItem(namespaceExtension, "schemas", "a");
   
   w.close();
   
   writer.setXmpMetadata(baos.toByteArray());

that creates this:
<pdfaExtension:schemas>
        <rdf:Bag>
          <rdf:li>a</rdf:li>
        </rdf:Bag>

No idea on how to go on. Using itext 5.5.8

Comment: @Giamma please add such clarifications to the question (there is an [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38593088/edit) link beneath it); code in comments is hard to read.

Comment: Added clarifications

Answer (score 3):

I am able to answer the question as phrased with iText5 although I consider this answer to be a bit of a "hack", in the sense that it makes no use of any iText semantic metadata objects, most of which seem to be deprecated. Note that in particular, `xmp.DublinCoreSchema`, `xmp.PdfSchema`, `xmp.XmpArray` and `xmp.XmpSchema` are deprecated while `xmp.CustomSchema` no longer exists.

The iText documentation is very poor in this regard.

The answer *should* be available [here](https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/miscellaneous/adding-metadata) or [here](https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/miscellaneous-itext5/custom-metadata-entry) or [here](https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/miscellaneous/clone-adding-metadata) but none of these helped. They only show how to manipulate the info section.

A solution *can* be derived from the thread [Adding & retrieve custom properties to PDF using XMP](http://itext.2136553.n4.nabble.com/Adding-amp-retrieve-custom-properties-to-PDF-using-XMP-td4658054.html) , but all the iText classes used are deprecated.

In the end, I noticed that *any* XML can be inserted via `stamper.setXmpMetadata(metadata)` where `metadata` is a `byte[]` containing XML. This XML could be created with DOM, but in the following quick-and-dirty a file is used.

```
package itext.sandpit;

import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfStamper;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.xmp.XMPException;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;


public class ItextSandpit {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws DocumentException,
            IOException,
            XMPException {

        // Create PDF
        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter.getInstance(
                document, new FileOutputStream("mypdf.pdf"));
        document.open();
        document.add(new Paragraph("Hello World!"));
        document.close();

        // Read metadata
        File fff = new File("metadata.xml");
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(fff);
        int byteLength = (int) fff.length(); //bytecount of the file-content
        byte[] metadatabytes = new byte[byteLength];
        fileInputStream.read(metadatabytes, 0, byteLength);

        // Add metadata
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("mypdf.pdf");
        PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream("mypdf_plus_xmp.pdf"));

        stamper.setXmpMetadata(metadatabytes);
        stamper.close();
        reader.close();
    }

}
```

Create a file `metadata.xml` and copy and paste the XML from the OP into this file, and run. To confirm that the metadata is really is inside the created PDF, `pdfinfo -meta mypdf_plus_xmp.pdf` yields

```
Producer:       iText® 5.5.12 ©2000-2017 iText Group NV (AGPL-version); modified using iText® 5.5.12 ©2000-2017 iText Group NV (AGPL-version)
CreationDate:   Tue Oct 10 21:01:21 2017
ModDate:        Tue Oct 10 21:01:21 2017
Tagged:         no
UserProperties: no
Suspects:       no
Form:           none
JavaScript:     no
Pages:          1
Encrypted:      no
Page size:      595 x 842 pts (A4)
Page rot:       0
File size:      3224 bytes
Optimized:      no
PDF version:    1.4
Metadata:
<rdf:Description rdf:about="" xmlns:pdfaExtension="http://www.aiim.org/pdfa/ns/extension/" xmlns:pdfaSchema="http://www.aiim.org/pdfa/ns/schema#" xmlns:pdfaProperty="http://www.aiim.org/pdfa/ns/property#" xmlns:pdfaType="http://www.aiim.org/pdfa/ns/type#" xmlns:pdfaField="http://www.aiim.org/pdfa/ns/field#"> <pdfaExtension:schemas>
<rdf:Bag>
<rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
<pdfaSchema:schema>ABI Assegni Schema</pdfaSchema:schema> <pdfaSchema:namespaceURI>http://abi.it/std/cheque/xmlns</pdfaSchema:namespaceURI> <pdfaSchema:prefix>assegni</pdfaSchema:prefix>
<pdfaSchema:property>
    <rdf:Seq>
<rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
<pdfaProperty:name>IDDocumento</pdfaProperty:name> <pdfaProperty:valueType>Text</pdfaProperty:valueType> <pdfaProperty:category>external</pdfaProperty:category> <pdfaProperty:description>Identificativo univoco del documento</pdfaProperty:description>
</rdf:li>
<rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
<pdfaProperty:name>datachiusura</pdfaProperty:name> <pdfaProperty:valueType>Date</pdfaProperty:valueType> <pdfaProperty:category>external</pdfaProperty:category> <pdfaProperty:description>Data e ora della produzione del file</pdfaProperty:description>
</rdf:li>
<rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
<pdfaProperty:name>oggettodocumento</pdfaProperty:name> <pdfaProperty:valueType>Text</pdfaProperty:valueType> <pdfaProperty:category>external</pdfaProperty:category> <pdfaProperty:description>Oggetto del documento</pdfaProperty:description>
</rdf:li>
<rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
<pdfaProperty:name>soggettoproduttore</pdfaProperty:name> <pdfaProperty:valueType>soggetto</pdfaProperty:valueType> <pdfaProperty:category>external</pdfaProperty:category> <pdfaProperty:description>Soggetto produttore</pdfaProperty:description>
</rdf:li>
<rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
<pdfaProperty:name>destinatario</pdfaProperty:name> <pdfaProperty:valueType>soggetto</pdfaProperty:valueType> <pdfaProperty:category>external</pdfaProperty:category> <pdfaProperty:description>Destinatario</pdfaProperty:description>
</rdf:li> </rdf:Seq>

</pdfaSchema:property>
</rdf:li>
</rdf:Bag>
</pdfaExtension:schemas>
</rdf:Description>
```

If possible, use <s>an iText "wrapper" such as</s> [PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/) or move to iText7.

Comment: PDFBox is not an iText wrapper, it is a different product.